# Verificar se retornou registros no select PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou precisando verificar se meu 'Select', está retornando registros para então carregar os dados na tela.   Abaixo segue o código que estou usando:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM USUARIOS;");

$linhas=mysqli_num_rows($sql); 

//eu preciso verificar aqui!!!!!

while ($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   echo "<td hidden='true'>". $linhas['id'] ."</td>";
   echo "<td>". $linhas['nome'] ."</td>";
}
```

Com base no código acima como devo verificar se a query retornou registros?

Porque caso não tenha retornado, irei exibir uma mensagem na tela, "Ainda não existe registro cadastrado".

O objetivo é: Quando não tiver registros, não retorna erro nenhum.

Obs.: quando tem dados cadastrados roda perfeitamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$total = mysqli_num_rows($sql); 
if($total === 0)
{
    echo 'Ainda não existe registro cadastrado';
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Muuuito obrigado amigo!!!!  Deu certinho!!

Comment: @PauloGalego marque a resposta como útil por favor já que resolveu seu problema !

Answer (score 0):

Com um construtor *if* da pra fazer.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM USUARIOS;");
$linhas=mysqli_num_rows($sql); 
if( $linhas > 0 ) :
    echo".<h5>."$linhas registros encontrados."</h5>";
    while ($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

       echo "<td>". $linhas['nome'] ."</td>";
    } 
else:
    echo"Ainda não existe registros !";
endif;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!